# what will be the best loss function for unet to predict the each pixel values?

Tags: objective-functions, image-segmentation, loss

[image]

I'm predicting the used 9 pictures to predict the  last picture 
so (40,40,9) -> unet -> (40,40,1)

but as you see the predict picture 
[image]

It's not just a mask(0or 1) its float 
so which loss function should I define to achieve the best Unet result? and why?